# Can't ping from inside to outside; misconfigured DNS

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have configured my network inteface according to [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-kvm-and-libvirt-on-centos-6.2-with-bridged-networking).

And now I can ping to server from my computer but I can't ping from server to outside world.

Note: I can ping 8.8.8.8

Can anyone explain whats the problem? Maybe because there is no gateway in eth0? but I need to have this configuration to run KVMs.

**EDIT:**

I think it's a DNS problem. I can ping IPs but I cant ping domains. sorry for misunderstanding.

```
# ping google.com
ping: unknown host
```

Comment: You contradict yourself. Since you *can* ping Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8), you *can* ping the outwide world. Though you claim you can't. What host can't you ping exactly so that you concluded that you don't have access to the outside world?

Comment: I think it's a DNS problem. I didn't really notice. I can ping IPs but I cant ping domains. sorry for misunderstanding. `# ping google.com`
`ping: unknown host google.com` Thanks

Comment: I have DNS setup in ifcfg-br0: `DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=209.139.209.33` What else can be the problem?

Comment: nslookup tells you...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a dns problem put the following in your `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 209.139.209.33
```

That would set up your DNS servers system-wide.

Comment: sorry for unrelated comment but can  I ask for a book about this stuff ? I'd appreciate if you name some of those.

Comment: Give [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Deployment Guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/index.html) a try.

Comment: The order of nameservers is important here or not?

Comment: Yes, it is important. They are listed by priority. See [resolv.conf(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) for details.